# how to use Regex for matching Functions and Capturing their Arguments

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file composed of several functions:

```
public int function(param1, param2, param3, param4,paramN)
{
}

public void function1(param1, param2)
{
}

public void function2()
{
}
```

I've made this code to get the functions name and parameters:

```
class Program
{


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Read the file as one string.
        System.IO.StreamReader myFile =
           new System.IO.StreamReader("E:\\new1.c");
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
        string Expression = myString;
        ///
        /// Get function name
        /// 
        var func = Regex.Match(Expression, @"\b[^()]+\((.*)\)$");

        Console.WriteLine("FuncTag: " + func.Value);
        string innerArgs = func.Groups[1].Value;
        ///
        /// Get parameters
        /// 
        var paramTags = Regex.Matches(innerArgs, @"([^,]+\(.+?\))|([^,]+)");

        Console.WriteLine("Matches: " + paramTags.Count);
        foreach (var item in paramTags)
            Console.WriteLine("ParamTag: " + item);
        myFile.Close();

        // Display the file contents.
        Console.WriteLine(myString);
        // Suspend the screen.
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.ReadKey();

    }
}
```

This works fine when I put `string Expression ="function(param1, param2, param3, param4,paramN)"`, but when I put instead the name of the file it doesn't work .I want to read all functions from the file and show all the functions with their parameters. How can I fix this?

Comment: You're not going to be able to parse pretty much any programming language with RegEx.  The languages simply aren't regular.  You're going to need to have a much more sophisticated lexer/parser to parse C code.

Comment: I've tried to work with this parser                https://code.google.com/p/cpp-ripper/                               but i didn't know how to get the functions name and parmeter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text editors not written for a specific programming language like UltraEdit or Notepad++ use also regular expressions to find names of functions / methods, function parameters, etc.

Therefore it is possible to use the regular expressions of those text editors also in C# coded applications.

---

**Attention!**

A regular expression approach to identify symbol names is never perfect and may return false positives or incorrect data.

For example using block or line comments within the parentheses of a function definition containing special characters like `)` or `{` in the comments will always produce wrong results. And of course the regular expression search would not eliminiate block and line comments within a function definition before as a C/C++/C# compiler does.

---

UltraEdit v21.20 uses in syntax highlighting wordfile `c_cplusplus.uew` the Perl regular expression string

```
^(?!if\b|else\b|while\b|[\s*])(?:[\w*~_&]+?\s+){1,6}([\w:*~_&]+\s*)\([^);]*\)[^{;]*?(?:^[^\r\n{]*;?[\s]+){0,10}\{
```

There is only 1 marking group in this expression which (usually) matches the name of the function / method.

The expression above matches in a C/C++ file everything from beginning of a function definition line up to opening brace, again with the limitation of not working for all function definition formats possible in C/C++ source files.

UltraEdit searches next inside the entire found string for `\(` and `\)` and extracts this string for further processing for function parameters using the expression `\s*([^,]+)`.

Therefore it would be possible to use

```
^(?!if\b|else\b|while\b|[\s*])(?:[\w*~_&]+?\s+){1,6}([\w:*~_&]+\s*)\(([^);]*)\)[^{;]*?(?:^[^\r\n{]*;?[\s]+){0,10}\{
```

which contains now 2 marking groups:

- The first one matches the name of the function / method.
- The second one matches everything between the parentheses.

So every second match can be searched next by `\s*([^,]+)` to get the function parameters with type (and comments) and on all found strings the [String.TrimEnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx) method should be used to remove all trailing spaces and tabs.